# python sum a value to all the elements in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of `int` and I'd like to sum a value to all of them.
The easy way of doing this is:

```
[x+y for x in my_list]
```

Is there a more efficient/pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: No, I don't think there is. Unless you use an external dependency like numpy: `list(np.array(x) + y)`. That's definitely not more efficient though.

Comment: `list(map(y.__add__, x))`

Comment: @Dragin. That is definitely not a duplicate.

Comment: Not really a duplicate, OP is asking if there is a more efficient way, not how to do it.

Comment: @Attersson. I feel like the "how" is implied, but that's definitely up for interpretation.

Comment: Yes that was addressed at Dragin, since the additional part reframes the question as different than the assumed duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way you have it is about as Pythonic as you can get working with lists. Any other option I can think of sacrifices either efficiency or legibility. You *could* do something like

```
list(map(y.__add__, my_list))
```

OR

```
list(map(partial(operator.add, y), my_list))
```

If you use an external dependency like numpy:

```
list(np.array(my_list) + y)
```

That's definitely not more efficient on its own though. It would only make sense if you wanted `np.array(my_list)` anyway, and didn't convert back to `list`.

Answer (score 1):

No, the list comprehension is, to date, the fastest.

As proved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map) `map` performs worse for all except few cases, in which `map` is only microscopically better.

It however depends on the context. For example if you were running this on a Spark RDD a lambda would allow parallelization.

Also a generator expression, if you don't need a new list, would save memory.